# Trying to reverse engineer a formula called "exponential_flat"

Tags: exponential-function

Here are the values I know:

```
A = 200
B = 1.75
C = 0
A2 = 1.8
B2 = 0.93
C2 = -0.64
T = 14
```

It is possible that some of these values are not used. The other formula (which was much easier) was simply called "exponential" and consisted of:

```
A = 240
B = 1.5
```

And the formula

```
Y = AB^X
```

This one consists of quite a few more variables and my googling for "exponential_flat" and variations of it were fruitless.

Here are some of the output values for values of X. These should be all correct but there is a possibility that some of them are off by a little.

```
1 - 448
2 - 717
3 - 1,147
4 - 1,853
5 - 2,936
6 - 4,698
7 - 7.516
8 - 12,026
9 - 19,241
10 - 30,786
11 - 49,258
```

The reason that some of the values may be off in this set is because the data was crowdsourced and I cannot confirm the numbers. Let me know if you have any more questions and I will answer them to the best of my ability. Thank you for any help you may be able to provide.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but the data in your last table almost exactly matches the function $y = 280\times1.6^x$.

Comment: Thank you Rahul, I will take that as a starting point and try to work it out from there. I am reverse engineering a game for fun and the different levels have different requirements for resources to advanced. I had thought this would just be an array of the values similar to what I have above but instead they use formulas to determine the resource cost. I have access to the variables used but cannot find the formula that uses them. The list I have is a crowdsourced list of the values needed. Thank you again for your help!